# Can two local users on two separate machines use SSH keys to authenticate without passwords?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, authentication

I have two local users (whose homes directories are listed under `/localhome/user`) on two separate VMs on the same network. They share the same `uid` (set in `/etc/passwd`) and the same username (`<user>`, here.)

```
useradd user -g user
```

I ran the following command on VM-A to create a a public key:

```
[user@VM-A] ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my.email@email.com" -b 4096
```

I copied the public key created on VM-A and placed it into `/localhome/dev/.ssh/authorized_keys` on VM-B. When I try to ssh from VM-A to VM-B, I get a password prompt.

```
[user@VM-A] ssh user@VM-B
password:
```

I have made sure permissions are set correctly (700 for both `.ssh` directories, 664 on VM-B's `authorized_keys`. I have also made sure both users are set to `/bin/bash` and not something like `nologin` in `/etc/passwd`.

I have also tried running `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` on both VM-A and VM-B.

To make sure I wasn't totally insane, I used my given account to see if I could `ssh` without a password. This account has access to a mounted "home" drive. I first tried to `ssh` from VM-A to VM-B and was asked for a password. I then created the key, updated `authorized_keys`, and tried again. This second time I successfully `ssh`'ed to the other VM using my account.

Is it possible to set up ssh keys on two different VMs using local users?

Comment: You are correct! My permissions were set to 664 on `authorized_keys`. Once I changed them to 600 I was successful in ssh'ing without a password. Would you please add this as an answer so I can confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your permissions on `authorized_keys` are too lax. You can fix them with

```
chmod u=rw,go= ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You will be able to see the reason for the failure to use certificates on the server in the security log - for example `/var/log/auth.log`.